# JMeter - FTP request to delete file

Tags: ftp, jmeter

FTP request sampler is working great, but its missing delete option. I appreciate if someone help me to achieve the same using JMeter.

Is there any method or custom script to perform delete ?

Comment: Downvoter, please explain yourself. This is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @RaGe, Not me, but this question good is good for http://sqa.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your option is to use [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) and extend [AbstractJavaSamplerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/AbstractJavaSamplerClient.html) to implement operation.

You can use [Apache FTPClient](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) to do this and all other commands on FTP.
Example:

```
...
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
client.connect(host, port);
client.login(loginname, password);
client.deleteFile(fileNameOnServer);
client.disconnect();
...
```

Comment: Urgh, is this the only way? Isn't there  a plugin to do FTP delete?